# Number after binomial coefficient

Tags: notation, binomial-coefficients

What does the number 2 mean in this picture?[image] 
[link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinomial_triangle)

Thanks. 
 Sorry I'm not a math expert.

I need this to make a program in C to generate a trinomial triangle for a guy who asked it on StackOverflow (it is his homework). Gotta earn that reputation. You know how it is!

Comment: It's already explained in your link.

Comment: I find this a horrible notataion. For me $\binom nk_2$ is the [Gaussian binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient) $\binom nk_q$ evaluated at $q=2$, which is quite something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scroll down the page you mentioned to see:

[image]

Actually it is the sum of of $x^k$ in $(1+x+1/x)^n$.
For e.g.:
In $$(1+x+x)^3=x^3+\frac1{x^3}+3 x^2+\frac3{x^2}+6 x+\frac6x+7$$
$$\binom 33_2=1,\binom3{-3}_2=1,\binom32_2=3,\binom3{-2}_2=3,\binom31_2=6,\binom3{-1}_2=6,\binom30_2=7 $$
Let's calulate $\binom42_2$:
$$\binom42_2=\underbrace{\frac{4!}{4!1!(4-4-1)!}}_{\mu=4,\;\nu=1}+\underbrace{\frac{4!}{2!2!(4-2-2)!}}_{\mu=2,\;\nu=2}+\underbrace{\frac{4!}{0!3!(4-0-3)!}}_{\mu=0,\;\nu=3}$$

Comment: @GerryMyerson does the edit satisfy you?