# Trinomial Summation Equation

Tags: multinomial-coefficients

I was looking at how to find trinomial coefficients with code and I was puzzled with this equation.

$$\binom n k _2 = \binom{n}{-k}_2$$
I know that (nCk) represents n choose k but what does the 2 at the bottom right do compared to binomial?

Comment: I will try to find another white image..

Comment: Your answer likely lies in [this MSE post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/916847/number-after-binomial-coefficient).

Comment: Thanks for the link ! @EeveeTrainer have flagged it as duplicate.